# Can i change the targetnamapce in WSDL ( In client side)

Tags: wsdl, cxf, xml-namespaces

I am generating the client side classes for invoking a 
WebService. When i invoked the webservice it is not working and I came to know that the server side is not accepting the namespace in the soap body. ( if i didn't pass the namespace in soap body it is working) Is there a way i can override the targetnamespace in the client side WSDL.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

First and easy way is updating client side wsdl with proper ones. If you generate your client automatically on runtime it will fix your problem.

If you already generate java classes using that WSDL, and you are using that client to connect services, you can still re-create java classes and update your class path.

And if you do not want to regenerate java classes, you can update each jax-ws and jaxb annotation with new targetnamespace.